# Generate sequence new values in dynamic sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

```
create sequence seq;

create table test(
    col int
);


do $$
begin
    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO test
    (col)
    select '||nextval('seq')||' from generate_series(1,5)' ;
end;
$$ language plpgsql
```

this results same values for all 5 rows, it seems `nextval('seq')` executed only once.

Question: How to generate sequence new values in dynamic sql as it works in normal SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're appending netval''s **result** to the string (which is your dynamic query).

So it's exactly the same as if you were doing this:

```
(...)
    EXECUTE 'insert into test 
    (col) 
    select 91533 from generate_series(1,5)';
(...)
```

Instead, you must make fetching number from sequence a part of your dynamic query.

```
(...)
    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO test
    (col)
    select nextval(''seq'') from generate_series(1,5)';
(...)
```

(I do not know postgres but this is more of a general dbms question. It would be the same in Oracle, but with different syntax).